# Glassfish Email Configuration with Exchange

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I have found quite a few references to configuring Glassfish for email, however I have not been able to solve my own issue and I am hoping that someone can help.

I have configured the JavaMail session in the Glassfish 3.12 console with the mailhost, user, sender address and description.  Transport protocol is set to SMTP and I have added a mail.smtp.host (and mail.smtp.auth=false) property.

The code I am using to send mail is as follows:

```
public class JndiMail {
    @Resource(name = "mail/[my-email]")
    private Session mailSession;

    public void sendMessage() {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        try {
          msg.setSubject("[app] Email Alert");
          msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress("user@domain",
            "User name"));
          msg.setText("Hello ");
          Transport.send(msg);
        }
        catch(MessagingException me) {
          System.out.println(me.toString());
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        }
      }
}
```

Every time the application sends an email, I have a log message saying that the local host has rejected the email.  I am trying to use a remote exchange server - not localhost.  I don't understand why the remote email server is not being accessed?  I realise that this should be fairly straight forward so I apologise if I have missed something.

These are the Glassfish logs:

```
[#|2013-03-26T10:00:39.334+1100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]|#]

[#|2013-03-26T10:00:39.334+1100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false|#]

[#|2013-03-26T10:00:39.334+1100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25, isSSL false|#]
```

Comment: Please post how did you configure mail session on Glassfish. What does the error message from Exchange exactly say?

Comment: I created a JavaMail resource through the admin console.  I used the name my-email (as above).  I did add additional properties to the resource - setting mail.smtp.host and mail.smtp.auth.  Debugging is also turned on.  I am not able to access the Glassfish logs from where I am at the moment, however the log messages were of the form "no response from localhost"

Comment: From localhost? That's suspicious, as you've mentioned that you are trying to connect to the remote host. Are your sure that you entered correct value in the "Mail Host" field in Glassfish? Btw, have you checked the connectivity between your server and Exchange?

Comment: Just back at the server and have added the actual logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked this out.  The solution is fairly straight forward.  When configuring the Javamail resource in Glassfish it is important to use the "mail/" prefix on the JNDI name.  I had assumed that Glassfish added this.  I found the solution by removing the injection from the above code and including the JNDI look up in the try catch:

```
try {
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();  
Session session = (Session) ctx.lookup("mail/MyEmail"); 
 Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

Comment: Would it still work with injection?  I am trying this, but I am still getting localhost:25